# integer to bit on C using pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I try to transform an int array  "d"(dimension nb_output) to an array sum(nb_output of "sum_size"bit).but the result isn't correct.When I use printf to verify table d, they are not same.Can anyone have a look on it?

```
    for(int ix=0;ix<nb_output;ix++)
    {
        printf("%d",d[ix]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int sum1;
    int ia;
    int array[100][8] = { 0 };
    for(int iy=0;iy<nb_output;iy++)
    {
        ia=d[iy];
        printf("%d\n",d[iy]);
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            sum1 = ia & 1;
            if (sum1 == 1)
            {
                array[iy][i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                array[iy][i] = 0;
            }
            ia = ia >> 1;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<sum_size;j++)
        {
            sum[iy][j]=array[iy][8-j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<nb_output;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sum_size;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: `array[iy][8-j]` breaks the array bounds when `j == 0`. And it's unknown what happens at the last iteration of the loop, since the incomplete code does not show where `sum_size` comes from.

Comment: Simpler is just `array[iy][i] = ia & 1;`

Comment: What is the max value of `nb_output`?

Comment: int sum_size=5@Weather Vane

Comment: int nb_output=16 @chux - Reinstate Monica

Comment: Thanks,but I dont understand why the value of table are different in this two position of printf@stark